# Deleting columns from joined attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes

After joining the attribute tables from two layers, I have a lot of duplicate columns on my table, making it hard to read.

However, when in "edit" mode, I am unable to select and delete columns.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Which QGIS and gdal version are your using?

Comment: I'm using QGIS 1.7.4, and saw I have GDAL 1.9 and 1.1.9 installers but am not sure anymore which I have installed. I am not doing anything to actively trigger GDAL, but I suppose QGIS might be doing something in the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the Table manager plugin?

It only works when you are **not** in editing mode. For Postgis/sqlite database tables you have to use the database manager.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that the join is done 'in memory' so you can't edit it until you save the joined file to a new file, which will take the new columns with it. You can then modify the schema of the newly created file.

Answer (score 0):

This is more what I needed: http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Deleting_a_column_from_an_attribute_table

This plugin makes it possible to graphically add and remove columns from layer attribute tables.

I now realise I should have specified in my question that I was not working with data in a PostGIS or other database, but being a newbie this didn't occur to me.